# App crashing on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

My App works perfectly at loading all the events and activities. However, when I try to load an Activity containing RecyclerView to show some stored strings. It crashes and `finish`. 
I don´t know if the syntax is wrong or maybe the logic of the code itself.

I am calling the activity from a listener

Object parceable to the new activity:

`final public FrasesProvisional frases = new FrasesProvisional();`

Method starting the activity:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.config:
             lanzarConfiguracion(null);
             break;

         case R.id.about:
             lanzarAbout(null);
             break;
         case R.id.mismotivaciones:
             abrirMotivaciones(null);
             break;
     }
     return true;
 }

 private void abrirMotivaciones(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, MotivacionesUser.class);
     startActivity(i);
 }
```

Activity content:

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.PersistableBundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

   /**
    * Created by Pablo on 14/01/2017.
    */
   public class MotivacionesUser extends AppCompatActivity {
       private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
       private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
       private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutMmanager;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.motivacionesrecycler);

           FrasesProvisional frases = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("frases");

           mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.motivaciones_recycler);
           // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
           // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
           mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
           //Init LayoutManager

           mLayoutMmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); //Podemos elegir entre LinearM, GridM o ScrappableM en relación al estilo que queramos
           mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutMmanager); //Set the Layout to the RrecyclerView

           mAdapter = new RecyclerAdaptador(frases.getArrayList()); //Especificamos el adaptador a usar y lo agenciamos al Recycler
           mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       }
   }
```

RecyclerView code:

```
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  /**
   * Created by Pablo on 14/01/2017.
   */
  public class RecyclerAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter < RecyclerAdaptador.ViewHolder > {

      private ArrayList < String > frases;

      public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
          // each data item is just a string in this case
          public TextView mTextView;
          public ViewHolder(View v) {
              super(v); //Inicializa el textview
              mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_recycler);
          }
      }

      public RecyclerAdaptador(ArrayList < String > frases) {
          this.frases = frases;
      }

      @Override
      public RecyclerAdaptador.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          //Create a new view
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.frase_recycler, parent, false);
         ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);

          return vh;
      }


      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

          //Get element of the data set at the position x and replace the content of the rextView with it

          holder.mTextView.setText(frases.get(position));

      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return frases.size();
      }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you create the activity through the following snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MotivacionesUser.class);
startActivity(i);
```

However in the activity you try to read out extra data in `FrasesProvisional frases = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("frases");`.

Since you never attached that data to the intent that would return `null`.
You then use it without checking if it was null at `new RecyclerAdaptador(frases.getArrayList());`, causing a NullPointerException and crashing your class.

Comment: the problem was a bad Parceable object creation. However, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Add a class variable

```
Context context;


public RecyclerAdaptador(Context context,ArrayList<String> frases) {
this.context=context
   this.frases = frases;
}
```

from activity

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdaptador(this,frases.getArrayList());
```

Comment: May I know the reason why this answer is downvoted ??

Comment: Because unless the problem is caused by the use of a missing or invalid context (and nothing in the `RecyclerAdaptador` class uses it), this answer has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Thanks but the problem was with the Parceable object when writeParceable was invoked.